# separate a website functions into group

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony2, I need to separate all functions of my website in to groups, a store can only use a function when  the group of that function is owned by the store,  the use case is quite simple, but when I try to design a way to do this, I find that it is quite nasty. my original idea is  to check whether a group is owned by a store in every action, actually ,every action  is a function, that means I have to mark a group for all actions, this design will need a tremendous work, do you have a better idea for this? I searched a lot, but didn't  find any bundle , or any resource like this, it seems this use case is very edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood well your question you need to have a role-based access to specific actions or to a set of actions. So, you can start creating a controller for each set of actions with a prefix that identifies the relative set.

## 1 - Creating a controller for a group of actions

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * @Route("/store")
 */
class StoreController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/foo/{bar}")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
     public function fooAction($bar) { }
}
```

## 2 - Group/Role-based set of actions

Now you need to [enable the access control](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#add-code-to-deny-access) for a certain set of routes. As an example:

```
#app/config/security.yml
  security:
  # ...

 firewalls:
     # ...
     default:
         # ...

 access_control:
     # require ROLE_STORE for /store*
     - { path: ^/store, roles: ROLE_STORE }
```

Comment: You  are right, add same  prefix  for  actions in a same group ,so  there  is no  need  to add mark for  every  action,  before  an  action  executes, I  can check that store whether it has that prefix belonged. My case is  a  little different,the  store is not a user, so can't add role  for  it using symfony default role system , but I can create a variation, thanks  for your clue.=)

Comment: If a little variation on this method would solve your problem, please accept it.